# Changing an image in header.php

Tags: themes, headers

I am trying to change an image uploaded to a theme header created by the company that designed my website.

I want to change the image to one that I have created, which isn't in the media library of WordPress. Is there a way to do this? This is the location currently, so not sure what is possible or not.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" width="270" height="90" alt="Logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You have 2 choices:

**Option 1**

Use an FTP manager such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), and navigate to the following folder:

`\wp-content\themes\YOUR-THEME'S-NAME\images\` and replace the `logo.png` file with any image you desire. To preserve the appearance, use an image with the same size of your current logo.

**Option 2**

Upload your logo through media library, and then replace the link to your logo with the link of the image you've just uploaded. Head over to `Appearance > Editor` and update your theme's `header.php` to something like:

`<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" class="logo"><img src="YOUR IMAGE URL HERE" width="270" height="90" alt="Logo"></a>`

Replacing the `YOUR IMAGE URL HERE` with your newly updated logo, of course.

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted.